# I'm getting many invalid values using "group by"

Tags: postgresql

In my query, i have to get many data which should be json-aggregated (with json_agg). The problem is that doing the regular way leads my script to get invalid/duplicated data. The number of invalid data is exactly the number of valid data of the greatest resulting json-array that i get. I think the problem is that "GROUP BY" takes every property I'm looking for. Here is an example of my query:

```
 SELECT
     o.property1 AS p1,
     json_agg(o.property2) AS p2,
     json_agg(o.property3) AS p3,
     json_agg(oto.property2) AS otop2
 FROM
     objectex o
     JOIN
         otherobjectex oto
     ON
         oto.property1 = o.property1
```

In this query, if o.property3 would return 4 values and o.property2 6. Then there will have 2 "null" values for property3. These null values are what I'm trying to ignore or remove. I tried using "DISTINCT" inside the json_agg(), but, i may have repeated values and I still want them. I would appreciate if the solution could be efficient and/or clean, too.

Comment: did you try to split this query in 2 levels?  like select property1 ,json_agg(property2), ... from (select distinct o.property1,o.property2 , ..)  as Q group by ...

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy, I don't think it's a good solution for me, since there was just an example. My query would need too many sub queries. But thanks for your comment, anyway.

Comment: kinda might be slow, but you cud write a small function to remove nulls from array

Answer (score 0):

where is your imagination, logical thinking? you could've easily modify that function to remove repeating values with ease. try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_unique_remove_null(anyarray) 
RETURNS anyarray AS $$ 
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT distinct i FROM unnest($1) i WHERE i IS NOT NULL) 
$$ LANGUAGE sql  IMMUTABLE;

 SELECT
     o.property1 AS p1,
     array_unique_remove_null(json_agg(o.property2)) AS p2,
     array_unique_remove_null(json_agg(o.property3)) AS p3,
     array_unique_remove_null(json_agg(oto.property2)) AS otop2
 FROM
     objectex o
     JOIN
         otherobjectex oto
     ON
         oto.property1 = o.property1
```

Comment: I had already think about that, but one of the problems is that the query kinda do "distributive" with the results, so if I have for p2 {"2", "3", "4} and for p3 {"abc", "def"}, I get for p2 {"2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"} and for p3 {"abc", "def", "abc", "def", "abc", "def"}. So the problem is not with the NULL values only, but with the invalid repetition of values. :( Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Well, I think this will return me the same I'm getting with json_agg(DISTINCT o.property2), or am I wrong? Because I still want the repeated values when they are valid, they may exist, but not excessively. I really need to jump over these "distributive" property of SQL returning me every combination of data. Thanks for your try, anyway. Btw, sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: it's not mine either. now i vaguely  get where the problem is, i hope.  are you doing unnesting on this query's results or something like that? your mistake might be aggregating those params separately.

Comment: you should try to aggregate with a single aggregate to a single array  something similar to this :  array_agg( array[o.property2 ,o.property3, oto.property2] ) -this is not working, just as an idea. i have no clue about json, but there are some functions to do this

Comment: No, I'm not using unnest. Not explicitly at least. I think the main problem is that PostgreSQL doesn't allows me to "choose" parameters to group by, i just have to put every single property there, so it matches every possibility. About json, I doesn't actually need it in the query, since it's not hard to convert it. I will give a look in these aggregate functions... Thanks, again.